# Сервер перестал отвечать на кроссдоменные запросы

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Сервер внезапно перестал отвечать на кроссдоменные запросы (может обновление ПО на хостинге)

клиент (js):

```
Request.onload = answer;
Request.open("post", "https://xxx.php", false);
Request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
Request.send(forSend);
```

сервер (php):

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('X-Content-Type-Options nosniff');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

в итоге в консоли:

```
Failed to load https://xxx.php: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'https://xxx.php'.
```

подскажите как разрешить запросы или в чем еще может быть проблема?

Comment: Посмотрите во вкладке сеть, какие заголовки у вас приходят с сервера на запрос `Request.send(forSend);`. Может там не только `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` нет, но и всех остальных.

Comment: спасибо, нашел ошибку просмотрев ответ, синтаксическая ошибка была на сервере, сам по невнимательности допустил)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оставьте только `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`